# How to Bypass login in Cypress + Cucumber

Tags: cucumber, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I am trying to Bypass UI login using Cypress with Cucumber. I have added `cy.session` in my `Cypress.Commands.add(login)` method.
But when I am trying to execute the scripts, clearing the session in each step in scenario file.
Ex:

```
Feature: Login
Scenario: Validate Login
Given Launch the URL And Login With Valid Credentials
When Login With Correct Username and Password
Then Verify Manage Home Page
```

In above scenario session is clearing in each step, like `Given, When, Then`.
I need to clear after each scenario in the feature file.
Please help me on this

```
Cypress.Commands.add('login', (username, password) => {
  cy.session([username, password], () => {
    cy.visit('/')
    cy.get(selectors.user_input,{ timeout: 60000 }).type(username)
    cy.get(selectors.login_button, { timeout: 60000 }).should('be.visible')
    cy.get(selectors.login_button).click()
    cy.wait(2000)
    cy.get(selectors.password_input, { timeout: 60000 }).should('be.visible')
    cy.get(selectors.submitButton, { timeout: 60000 }).should('be.visible')
    cy.get(selectors.password_input).type(password)
    cy.get(selectors.submitButton).click()
    cy.get(selectors.homePage, { timeout: 60000 }).should('be.visible')
  })
})
```

Or, please help me how to avoid login in each scenario in feature file.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try putting the login feature into `beforeEach`?

That is how I use cy.session:

```js
describe('...', () => {

    beforeEach(() => {
        cy.login()         
    })

    it('test a', () => {

    ...
    })
...
})
```

{{edit}} 2nd possibility is to preserve Cookies to stay logged in:

```js
describe('...', () => {
beforeEach(function () {
        cy.preserveAllCookiesOnce()
    })
it('test a', () => {

    ...
    })
...
})
```

Comment: cypher_null, I have tried each hooks in cucumber and cypress. Since I am using Cucumber, I have to bypass UI login in each scenario to save time.

Comment: A second possibility that I have been using before is to store cookies so I stay logged in until the end of the spec file. I put this after the describe before the first 'it' instance: ```beforeEach(function () {cy.preserveAllCookiesOnce()})``` That way I would only need to log in once at the beginning of each spec file

Comment: "cypher_null". thanks for your solution. I understand your  piece of code. But in my case, I use cucumber so in my test file I have to write Given, When , Then, not like describe , it.

Comment: @cypher_null - Please can you suggest any solution for the BDD approach way?